# WPF Combobox based databinding Textbox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, textbox, conditional-statements

I have been trying to find a solution to this one but could not find a relevant answer online.

I have a bunch of text boxes that I need to populate with data, for example in my case address. I have a combo box that is bound to an enum and has a list of values to select from

Home, Office, MainOffice, Laboratory. etc. When I make a selection on combobox, I need to populate its address in the text boxes below. I can get Home address from object X, Office Address from Object Y, MainOffice from Z. How do I do this conditional databinding using combobox selection. Please advise.

These are the options that I could select

```
public enum MailToOptions
{
    Home,
    Office,
    CorporateOffice,
    Laboratory,
}



    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Content="Mail To:" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Name="MailToComboBox" 

     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odp}}"    
     SelectionChanged="HandleMailToSelectionChangedEvent" >

    </ComboBox>
    <!-- Agency ID -->


    <!-- Name -->
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Content="Name" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Order.Agency.PartyFullName" Mode="TwoWay" />
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <!-- Address Line 1 -->
    <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Content="Address 1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Order.Agency.AddressLine1" Mode="TwoWay"     />
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Could you post some code showing what you have got so far?

Comment: Benjamin, I just updated my question to show some code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way would be to make the items in your `ComboBox` objects, and bind your text fields to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`

For example,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="AddressList" ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Street, ElementName=AddressList}" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.City, ElementName=AddressList}" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.State, ElementName=AddressList}" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ZipCode, ElementName=AddressList}" ... />
```

A cleaner way would be to set the `DataContext` of whatever panel holds the TextBoxes

```
<ComboBox x:Name="AddressList" ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

<Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AddressList}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Street}" ... />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding City}" ... />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding State}" ... />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ZipCode}" ... />
</Grid>
```

You can either bind the ComboBox to something like an `ObservableCollection<Address>`, or set the `ItemsSource` manually in the code behind.

I'd recommending binding, however to set it manually in the code behind it would look something like this:

```
var addresses = new List<Addresses>();
addresses.Add(new Address { Name = "Home", Street = "1234 Some Road", ... });
addresses.Add(new Address { Name = "Office", Street = "1234 Main Street", ... });
...
AddressList.ItemsSource = addresses;
```

Comment: Displaying the selectedItem using 'DisplayMemberPath' instead of setting an itemTemplate with a dataTemplate helped me out